# Behaviour of RISC-V mulh assembly instruction

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, multiplication, riscv, instruction-set

The RISC-V reader states that mulh rd, rs1, rs2 "multiplies x[rs1] by x[rs2], treating the values as two'cplement numbers, and writes the upper half of the product to x[rd]"

So I am trying to multiply two signed 64 bit numbers and get a signed 128 bit result:

```
 mulh t0, a0, a1
 mul t1, a0, a1
```

And I'd expect that t0 would hold the upper 64 bits and t1 the lower 64 bits, but if a0= 0x7fffffffffffffff (ie MAX-INT) and a1 = 2, I get:

t0 = 0, t1=0xfffffffffffffffe as though I'd carried out an unsigned multiplication. And not t0 = 1 , t1= 0x7fffffffffffffff which appears to me to be the correct answer for two's complement arithmetic.

Now - in writing this out, I can see why I get t1=0xffffffffffffff, but I still don't get why I get t0=1, which would allow me to implement some logic to correct the sign bit in t1.

What have I got wrong here? I used to have rather complex bit-by-bit long multiplication algorithm for this, but this seemed so much simpler, but it (obviously) doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `t0:t1` (concatenation of the two registers) is to be interpreted as the 128-bit full product of `a0` and `a1`. Sign information is going to be in `t0`. Here, `t0<63>` = `(a0*a1)<127>` is 0, so the product is positive.

Comment: Thanks - get this now - could you turn that into answer and I will accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 128-bit answer to 2 x 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF is

```
0x0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFE
  |------ t0 ----||----- t1 ----|
  |
  |
  +-- the sign bit is the uppermost bit of this hex digit
```

Because you're multiplying two positive numbers, the answer is the same bit pattern whether you choose signed or unsigned multiplication.